# Unit Testing LiveData returned from Room inside a method

Tags: android, junit, android-room, android-livedata, android-instrumentation

I have a method which gets a LiveData object from from the DAO layer of Room and then does some operations on the LiveData object.

Whenever I try to do `dataStorage.getAllSections()` it returns a LiveData object, and the value is always null. (My DB is prepopulated)

I have declared the JUnit Rule for LiveData

```
@get:Rule
val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

In my actual class if I create a extension function to wait on the LiveData like this,

```
private fun <T> LiveData<T>.blockingObserve(): T? {
    var value: T? = null
    val latch = CountDownLatch(1)

    val observer = Observer<T> { t ->
        value = t
        latch.countDown()
    }

    observeForever(observer)

    latch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    return value
}
```

and do,

```
dataStorage.getAllSections.blockingObserve()
```

The unit test runs fine. I do not get a null pointer exception. 
I have even tried running the test with `runBlocking` but that does not help either.

```
This is my method I am trying to test: 

@VisibleForTesting
fun buildDataFromDB(): LiveData<List<SectionModel>> {

    Logger.d(TAG, "Building data from DB")

    val sections = dataStorage.getAllSections() 
    // sections.value is always null even though my DB is populated 
    sections.value?.forEach { section ->
        // Do something 
        }
    }

    Logger.d(TAG, "Building data from DB completed")

    return sections
}
```

This is my test case:

```
@Test
fun test_buildDataFromDb() = runBlocking {
    val result = appDataProvider.buildDataFromDB().blockingObserve()
    // asserts
}
```